# Starting NodeJS with a specific configuration

Tags: node.js

I am using some NodeJS package, and I would like to start NodeJS with a specific configuration (more precisely, `--abort-on-uncaught-exception`).

However, this package (as well as any other package I believe), runs NodeJS "under the hood", i.e., when I call the package from a command line, I actually call NodeJS with the source code of the package (or something like that).

How can get the package to run NodeJS with this specific configuration?

I am guessing, possibly something that I need to add in the `package.json` (npm configuration) file.

Comment: As a first thought, I'd put a wrapper script for `node` in ~/bin (at top of my $PATH) to manage the default arguments for node without altering other code.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, are you running node like this `node --abort-on-uncaught-exception index.js` and it doesn't work?

Comment: You can add a `scripts`section to `package.json`. See https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts

Comment: @rodrigoap: No, I am running some node package directly from a command line. When doing so, as I understand it, it is in fact node which is executed, with the source code of that package as input. In other words, I call the package from a command line, and as a result, node executes it. Now, how do I make node run under a specific configuration here?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer!!!

Generally speaking, I realized that I should simply run from a command-line:

```
node --abort-on-uncaught-exception ../node_modules/.bin/<the package>
```

Then I recalled reading something about it being different on Windows.

Instead of using the package name, one needs to use the package source code file name.

In my case (as in many other cases, I presume), I needed to run this instead:

```
node --abort-on-uncaught-exception ..\node_modules\<the package>\build\cli.bundled.js
```

Or you can probably even use normal slashes and make it compatible with all other operating systems:

```
node --abort-on-uncaught-exception ../node_modules/<the package>/build/cli.bundled.js
```